# Unassign background color when next div is selected Javascript

Tags: javascript

With my current code, I was able to create a click event for when a user clicks on a div to give it a blueish background color with a toggle of an active class using css. Im trying to solve nos how to deselect the first div if a user clicks on a different div. Currently if a div is clicked it turns blue, and if a different div is clicked it also turns blue. Trying to figure out how to make the first div unselect. Thank you in advance,, any tips much appreciated! :)

```js
let header = document.getElementsByClassName("options__container--option");

for (i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
  header[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
}
```

```css
.options__container--option.active {
  background-color: #1b8684;
}
```

```html
<main class="subscription__container">
  <section id="preferences" class="subscription__container--preferences box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">
        How do you drink your coffee?
      </h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="capsule" type="radio" data-preference="Capsule" value="Capsule" name="preferences" checked />
        <label for="capsule"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="filter" type="radio" data-preference="Filter" value="Filter" name="preferences" />
        <label for="filter"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and V60.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="espresso" type="radio" data-preference="Espresso" value="Espresso" name="preferences" />
        <label for="espresso"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful experience.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

[image: current]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go about in two ways. Either you store a reference to the active element in a variable and use that to remove the class, or you just loop through all `.options__container--option` to remove the class `.active` in all of them. Because you already have all the header elements stored, I will go with the second solution.

EDIT: added code for sectionsId, which was asked for in the comments.

```js
let header = document.getElementsByClassName("options__container--option");

function getSectionId(option) {
  return option.parentNode.parentNode.id;
}

for (i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
  header[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    let isNotActive = !this.classList.contains("active");
    let sectionsId = getSectionId(this);
    
console.log(`sectionsId: ${sectionsId}`);

    for (const option of header) {
      if (getSectionId(option) == sectionsId) {
        option.classList.remove("active");    
      }
    }

    /* the same loop as above, but in the form of a for loop 

    let option;
    for (let j = 0; j < header.length; j++) {
      option = header[j];

      if (getSectionId(option) == sectionsId) {
        option.classList.remove("active");
      }
    }
    */

    if (isNotActive) {
      this.classList.add("active");
    }        
  });
}
```

```css
.options__container--option.active {
  background-color: #1b8684;
}
```

```html
<main class="subscription__container">
  <section id="preferences" class="subscription__container--preferences box">
    <div class="question__container">
      <h3 class="question__container--title">
        How do you drink your coffee?
      </h3>
      <img class="question__container--img" src="../assets/plan/desktop/icon-arrow.svg" alt="arrow" />
    </div>
    <div class="options__container">
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="capsule" type="radio" data-preference="Capsule" value="Capsule" name="preferences" checked />
        <label for="capsule"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Capsule</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          Compatible with Nespresso systems and similar brewers.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="filter" type="radio" data-preference="Filter" value="Filter" name="preferences" />
        <label for="filter"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Filter</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          For pour over or drip methods like Aeropress, Chemex, and V60.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="options__container--option">
        <input id="espresso" type="radio" data-preference="Espresso" value="Espresso" name="preferences" />
        <label for="espresso"></label>
        <h4 class="options__container--title">Espresso</h4>
        <p class="options__container--description">
          Dense and finely ground beans for an intense, flavorful experience.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Can you pls explain the keyword option in the for loop Rickard

Comment: It's the same as header[i] in a typical for loop. You should name your `header` variable to `headers`, because there are several of them, and I would in that case write `for (const header in headers)`, where "header" would be the same as "header[i]".

Comment: I see, option was used a parameter, and then you used it for option.classList.remove etc.

Comment: Exactly. I updated the code with an example of how the equivalent of the for loop would look like. I find the (newer) `for of` loop is easier to write, easier to read, and takes less characters to write.

Comment: Thank you Rickard, this is working. Yet I have an issue. Above in my html is only one category with 3 options. I left out in the html a remaining of 4 categories with as well 3 options. I am able select an option in the first category, but if i go to the second category, the first option gets deselected. Is there a way to keep it selected when I move to a different category?

Comment: thank you for taking the time to assist me

Comment: No worries. It's past midnight, so I'm going to sleep now. :) You need to separate not only what's being clicked but where. From what I can tell, your `sections` seems to have an (unique) id, so I will use that. I added a `console.log` just to showcase how it works in my code. You can traverse the DOM structure by using parentNode (go up "a level") and childNodes (go deeper down "a level").

Comment: Hey Rickard, can i ask you for some assistance pls?

Comment: I would rather that you started a new post. :)

Comment: Hey Rickard, I created a new post, yet I will discuss a bit here. With the code that you helped out with, it is only getting executed if the user clicks on the outer edge of the div box. If clicked in the middle, does not run. I tried to do something such as input[type=radio]:checked + label and to change the background color. Yet I was unable to target it as such. If you have time can you pls assist me with solving this.